# jquery-ui draggable interfering with touch scroll

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-ui, touch

It's my understanding that jQuery UI totally ignores touch events and people wanting to use touch events have had to use touch-punch to map touch events into mouse events.  However, the newer versions of UI seem to be interfering with built in touch events such as scrolling even though they should be ignoring those events.

I have jQuery UI `draggable` elements that work fine.  However, when using a touch device and attempting to scroll the window with that element below the touch point, the screen won't scroll.  If jQuery UI is ignoring touch events, why is this happening?

I've found that older versions of UI don't have this issue.  The version I'm using is 1.11.4 .

Just to re-iterate:  I'm not trying to make the `draggable` elements draggable on a touch device.  I just want it to ignore the touch events and allow regular scrolling to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the library is ignoring actions, but the CSS is setting `touch-action: none` which is what is causing the functionality I'm seeing.